# Google SMTP not working with AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtplib

Hi I am using gmail smtp with port 587. that is working fine on local but not working on production. my website is hosted on AWS EC2.

[image: img]

I have added the port in security group as well.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping your instance? Have you setup your VPC/Subnet configuration to allow internet based traffic (not private IP's, allocating public DNS names)?